# Асинхронный запрос Android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, httpurlconnection

Доброй ночи, проблема такая.
Есть activity и есть ApiController нужно из активити выполнить метод в апиконтроллере, который отправит post запрос на сервер, и при получении ответа изменится UI.  Это нужно сделать асинхронно без блокировки UI. Не подскажете в как это реализовать (android)

Comment: А что конкретно не получается?

Comment: @post_zeew получается сделать только синхронный запрос, при выполнении которого подвисает UI, как сделать чтобы при вызове метода в ApiController можно было передать параметры запроса и "кусок" кода который выполнится в UI после выполнения запроса. Как это реализованно в iOS. Вот пример. onCompletion это метод, переданный из UI, который вызовется после получения ответа от сервера http://pastebin.com/jpdT1kq9

Comment: А чем вас не устраивает колбэк onPostExecute() класса AsyncTask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте либу [OkHttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp).

Подключите так:

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0'
```

С ней запросы выглядят так:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
    .url("http://publicobject.com/helloworld.txt")
    .build();

client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
  @Override public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

  @Override public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
    if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

    Headers responseHeaders = response.headers();
    for (int i = 0, size = responseHeaders.size(); i < size; i++) {
      System.out.println(responseHeaders.name(i) + ": " + responseHeaders.value(i));
    }

    System.out.println(response.body().string());
  }
});
```